# Create simple Google Cardboard

Tags: android, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I have a got a Google Card board with me and have basic knowledge of Android development. So I was thinking of creating a simple Google Cardboard App, which would show an image (panoramic or photosphere) with VR effect.

Can any one guide on how to do this, thanks in advance.

Comment: We don't really appreciate asking for links to resources on our site. Please see our FAQ.

Comment: @K.L. Thanks, I have edited the question. But I could manage to get a github link myself.

Answer (score 3):

By far the easiest way to make your first Cardboard app is using the [Google Cardboard Plugin for Unity](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/unity/).

If you're not already familiar, [Unity](https://unity3d.com) is a free game engine that lets you quickly create 3D games for almost any platform, including Android.  I made a 3D shooting game for cardboard in Unity in only two days, and I've never made a game before.

Answer (score 1):

[RajawaliCardboard](https://github.com/ejeinc/RajawaliCardboardExample) App module is the perfect example of how to do it. It's easy to implement and works well with images from photosphere and panorama images.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/cardboard/android/

Comment: I have already gone through it and download the Sample Code, but couldn't understand it fully since I'm not familiar with OpenGL

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

[Google Cardboard 360](https://github.com/pollux-/GoogleCardBoardVr-360-PhotoSphere)